# Active class at Bootstrap affix scrollspy doesn't work for hidden div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've used bootstrap affix at my sidebar. It work's fine at normal scenario. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/naxh4t2v/) of normal behavior which is working fine. If you look on this fiddle, you'll see that blue background is achieved with `.list-group-item` clicking I mean, `.active` class is achieved at the `.list-group-item`.

[image]

But, at my scenario, that sidebar is appeared after 2-3 screens. All is happened in same page so, I have to make that screen hidden. For simplicity, I put the affix content and related content under one hidden step only [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/k16qmkej/) and noticed that affix `.active` doesn't achieved for this scenario! How can I make it working properly when those affix content come from hidden div?

Comment: That's scrollspy not affix. It doesn't work with hidden sections. If you change your question with the correct terms, perhaps someone will help.

Comment: Actually, I followed this link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix. So, I used the affix term. Basically, I am not sure should it be scrollspy or affix

Comment: if an element is hidden it's offset in document is not available. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is scrollspy, the name implies spying on the scroll position. Affix is fixing something position:fixed.

Comment: ok, got it. I like to edit my title according to your point. But, as it's related with affix, I like to keep that term too. So, will it be appropriate if I changed the title like this? " Active class at Bootstrap affix scrollspy doesn't work for hidden div". Please, never mind. I am not expert with this term. That's why, I need to ask this way. Thanks @Christina

Comment: @charlietfl, I am not sure, did you understand my problem or not. But, according to your question, I might be finding an way making them available when they come from hidden div.

Comment: Updated my answer, i think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [bootstrap documentation found here:](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

> Non-:visible target elements ignored Target elements that are not
>   :visible according to jQuery will be ignored and their corresponding
>   nav items will never be highlighted.

So basically the scrollspy elements will not be highlighted when the containers are set to `display:none;` However you can use `visibility: hidden;` but you will still see a scroll-bar on the page if your content is long enough. I used your js.fiddle and made a [working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/k16qmkej/1/). As you can see i removed the JQuery and used pure CSS to show/hide as well as changed the `display` elements to `visibility`. Hope that helps.

**EDIT***

Ok after messing with the JQuery and reading through the documentation I found out you can refresh the scrollspy after the DOM has been changed and with this JQuery your application will work as intended.

```
$('body').on('click', '.show', function() { 
    $(this).parents().next('.box-creator-section').slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() == "Show") { 
       $(this).text("Hide"); 
    } 
    else { 
       $(this).text("Show"); 
       /*
        $('.sidebar').each(function () {
          var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
       });
       */
    };
    $('body').scrollspy('refresh');
});
```

I basically added `$('body').scrollspy('refresh');` after the show/hide call. [Second updated js.fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k16qmkej/2/)

Comment: ok, I got the point. But, instead of visibilty: hidden; it'll be great for me if it can be made working for display: none; by anyhow (may be, by some customized script). Because, my original scenario is something like, that section will come after so many button action and every step cover the whole page something like it seems going a new page by every button action but all is happened in one page. So, display: none is more good for me